# Breeze expand query fails with Object #<Object> has no method 'getProperty'

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I'm using Breeze 1.4.2 with Entity framework 5. This is my query:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery
        .from("TrendStudies")
        .where("Id", "==", studyId)
        .expand("Charts");
```

This works fine if I remove the .expand -part, but otherwise it fails with the following error message:

```
Object #<Object> has no method 'getProperty'
```

Apparently this error is thrown from the breeze function:

```
function updateRelatedEntityInCollection(relatedEntity, relatedEntities, targetEntity, inverseProperty) {
        if (!relatedEntity) return;
        // check if the related entity is already hooked up
        var thisEntity = relatedEntity.getProperty(inverseProperty.name);
        if (thisEntity !== targetEntity) {
            // if not - hook it up.
            relatedEntities.push(relatedEntity);
            relatedEntity.setProperty(inverseProperty.name, targetEntity);
        }
    }
```

My relatedEntity here is just

`Object {Id: 104, TrendStudyId: 156, Order: 1, ChartClassId: 1}`

So why is my relatedEntity missing the getProperty method here? Should it be initialized somewhere?

Comment: Are you setting your metadata or getting it from EF?  What does that relationship look like in your model?

Comment: I'm getting it from EF. In the model I have 
`[InverseProperty("TrendStudy")]
public virtual ICollection<Chart> Charts { get; set; }`
in my TrendStudy class and
`[Required]
        public int TrendStudyId { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("Charts")]
        public virtual TrendStudy TrendStudy { get; set; }`
in my Chart class.

Seems that the query only fails when there are Charts associated with the TrendStudy.