# Breeze - expand results in Object #<Object> has no method 'getProperty' Query failed

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5, breeze

In my edmx model are 2 related tables: Challenge and ChallengeNote (has FK back to ChallengeID)

I can do this in breeze all day long

`var qry = dataservice.getQuery("Challenges");`

However, this fails every time:

`var qry = dataservice.getQuery("Challenges").expand("ChallengeNotes");`

The searchFailed is called and is the only error information in the console.

```
return dataservice.execute(qry.inlineCount(true))
        .then(seachSucceeded)
        .fail(searchFailed);
```

- Does Breeze support relational data like this?
- Does one need to write some custom code to support?
- What am I missing?

Here's related answered question, but I was already following (unless I missed something) the answer's solution (and why I have the 2 context.Configuration settings in my ContextProvider).
[breezejs-error-when-loading-an-entity-with-related-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032201/breezejs-error-when-loading-an-entity-with-related-data)

Here's another similar question that's been unanswered [breeze-expand-query-fails-with-object-object-has-no-method-getproperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275376/breeze-expand-query-fails-with-object-object-has-no-method-getproperty)

Here's my provider code (want to use the BeforeSaveEntity override further on in the project):

```
public class ModelProvider : EFContextProvider<ModelEntities>
{
    public ModelProvider()
        : base() 
    {
        this.Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;            
    }
}
```

Here's my controller code:

```
[BreezeController]
public class DataController : ApiController
{
    readonly ModelProvider _contextProvider = new ModelProvider();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Challenge> Challenges()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Challenges.Include(x => x.ChallengeNotes);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<ChallengeNote> ChallengeNotes()
    {       
        return _contextProvider.Context.ChallengeNotes;
    }
}
```

When I browse to the URL, it's including the related entity:
`http://localhost:53644/breeze/data/Challenges?$filter=Active%20eq%20true&$top=10&$expand=ChallengeNotes&$inlinecount=allpages`

Here is the data coming from the Controller
[image: json results]

At this point all things, imo, are pointing to Breeze configuration on either the Server or Client.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breeze absolutely does support this, but you do need to make sure that your Entity Framework model is set up correctly. Take a look at the DocCode sample in the Breeze zip for a number of examples of using both expand (client side) or EF include (server side) clauses.

One guess about your problem is that you are using the Breeze camelCasing naming convention and therefore your "expand" clause should be

```
var qry = dataservice.getQuery("Challenges").expand("challengeNotes");
```

i.e. "challengeNotes" (note the casing) is the name of the client side property that corresponds to a server side property of "ChallengeNotes".  To clarify, "expand" clauses take the names of client side "properties" as parameters and property names are what are transformed as a result of the Breeze.NamingConvention.

In contrast, a query resource name i.e. "Challenges" in your example is the name of the server side resource ( as a result of marking your "Challenges" method with the [HttpGet] annotation.  This name is NOT affected by the NamingConvention.

Side notes: Your example has both an expand and an Include clause. Either of these is sufficient all by itself.  You do not need both.  In general you can either include an "expand" clause in your client side query OR have an Entity Framework "Include" clause on the server. The advantage of the first is that you can control the expand on the client, the advantage of the second is that you can insure that every query for a specified resource always fetches some related entities.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Since I'm a C# guy, I was keeping the casing to match my DB. My first attempt based on your feedback was to change it to `.expand('challengeNotes)` and I got a 404 from my WebAPI. So I added in the `NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();` and tried with the challengeNotes. Now I get this error in my web page: 

`unable to locate property: Active on entityType: Challenge:#WebApp.Models Query failed ` 

(Challenge has the Active field)
I don't see the request going to the server in Chrome F12 tools. I did verify that the Metadata sent from my WebAPI.

Comment: My last error was because the casing was wrong. So I refactored my client code to use camelCasing and still had issues. In comparing my code to samples, I noticed that I didn't have a MetadataStore. So I added 

`var store = new breeze.MetadataStore();
        var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ serviceName: serviceName, metadataStore: store });`

to my dataservice.js file.

I'm almost there -- no errors and my data returns (with Notes!), but I am now getting properties with my data instead of the observable() as it was before. 

- Is there a setting I am missing?

Comment: I've tried various different combinations - but it's consistently this: -- If I have the expand, I get the relational results but they are just JS objects and there's no entityAspect property. If I don't have the expand, I get my entity with  Knockout Observable objects for the fields <- is what I want. @Jay Traband

Comment: First thing I would do is remove the ".Include(x => x.ChallengeNotes" from your server code, because it obscures the "expand" you are trying to perform.  Next, the only reason that you will get an entity without it being observable is if Breeze cannot find an entity type defined in the metadataStore whose name matches the name in the json being returned to the client. When this happens, Breeze assumes that what is being returned is a projection and just returns a raw javascript object.  See the MetadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName method and docs for more info.

Comment: After much digging, I've found the root of the issue -- Without the .expand(), my Controller is returning `$type: MySPA.Models.Challenge, MySPA` in results[]. When the .expand() is added to the query, it's returning: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary 2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]]`. So I've got to dig to figure out this issue now. Is this something in Breeze.WebApi or I do need to mess with MS.WebAPI? (I'm really liking Breeze - thanks for the library!) @Jay Traband.

Comment: @CarolAndorMartenLiebster I have same problem, have you found solution ?

Comment: Solved it, if you still need help, see this link (I believe same solution will help you too): http://stackoverflow.com/a/20365167/1284262