# Breeze newValue.getProperty is not a function

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, breeze

I've updated to new version of breeze and ef 6. And after I did this, I get error

```
newValue.getProperty is not a function
```

Whenever I try to execute expand query. (for "normal" queries everything is fine )

So here is my model for Mucsle:

```
    public int MuscleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int MuscleGroupId { get; set; }
    public  MuscleGroup MuscleGroup { get; set; }
```

And for MuscleGroup:

```
    public int MuscleGroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public  ICollection<Muscle> Muscles { get; set; }
```

Here is my DtabaseContext Configuration:

```
public WebDatabaseContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }
```

And I try to fetch data like this:

Function in dataService:

```
getAllIncluding: function(controllerAction, including) {
            var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from(controllerAction).expand(including);
            return manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded).fail(getFailed);

            function querySucceeded(data) {
                items = data.results;
                return data.results;
            }
        }
```

Call of function:

```
$scope.getAllMuscles = function() {
        adminCrudService.getAllIncluding("Muscles", "MuscleGroup")
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

    };
```

With older version of breeze and EF5 this works, so I wonder what am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

I believe, I've found what causes problem, when I enter in  url:

```
breeze/Service/Muscles?$expand=MuscleGroup
```

With "old" (older version of breeze, and EF 5) settings, output is this:

```
[{"$id":"1","$type":"Test.Domain.Model.MuscleGroupAggregate.Muscle, Test.Domain.Model","MuscleId":1,"Name":"Biceps","NameInLatin":"","ImageUrl":null,"MuscleGroupId":1,"MuscleGroup":null},

{"$id":"2","$type":"Test.Domain.Model.MuscleGroupAggregate.Muscle, Test.Domain.Model","MuscleId":3,"Name":"Triceps","NameInLatin":"","ImageUrl":null,"MuscleGroupId":1,"MuscleGroup":null},
```

And with EF 6 and latest version of breeze:

```
    [{"$id":"1","$type":"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]], mscorlib","MuscleGroup":

{"$id":"2","$type":"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]], mscorlib","MuscleGroupId":1,"Name":"TestMuscleG1","Description":"","ImageUrl":null},"MuscleId":1,"Name":"Test2","NameInLatin":"","ImageUrl":null,"MuscleGroupId":1},

{"$id":"3","$type":"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]], mscorlib","MuscleGroup":

{"$id":"4","$type":"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]], mscorlib","MuscleGroupId":1,"Name":"TestMuscleG1","Description":"","ImageUrl":null},"MuscleId":2,"Name":"32r23r","NameInLatin":"","ImageUrl":null,"MuscleGroupId":1}]
```

So difference is in $type, and in "new" output, even tough, in database I have only two entries, I got 4 items.

Comment: I can't replicate this.  Are you sure that you are using the right  EF6 nuget packages? These are the packages that are NOT labeled (obsolete).  My suggestion would be to remove ALL nugets and then reapply the new ones.

Comment: I've created new solution, copied code there, added all packages again, with same result ... I've noticed smth. interesting also, in my 'old' code (old ef, and old breeze) I call getAllIncluding like with parameter MuscleGroups, and now when I updated everything i get bad request, unless I change it to MuscleGroup, then I get error described above, and this happens every time when using expand, but i can create new Muscle with it's MuscleGroup without problem, so problem is with breeze's expand (when I type expand query in browser, it works)

Comment: This sounds like a metadata issue.  Can you check the client side metadata and see how it differs between your EF5 and EF6 projects?  My guess is that your EF6 model may have an issue.

Comment: How can that be ? I've just copy&pasted my model to new project and added via Nuget EF,

Comment: Metadata is very unreadable, but i managed to find this (it's form ef 6): `{"name":"MuscleGroupId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"false"}],"navigationProperty":{"name":"MuscleGroup","relationship":"Self.MuscleGroup_Muscles","fromRole":"MuscleGroup_Muscles_Target","toRole":"MuscleGroup_Muscles_Source"}}`

Comment: I meant for you to use the MetadataStore api to look at the metadata. i.e. using something like var muscleType = myEntityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Muscle"); muscleType.getProperties()... See the api guide for more info.  And then do your comparison.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but I couldn't spot any differences

Comment: Please check your refs.  I think that you are using WebApi (and not WebApi2) refs with EF6.  Take a look at the DocCode sample in the Breeze zip. This is using the latest EF6 and WebApi2 and has several examples of expand just like yours.

Comment: I will check, this, but I'm pretty sure I'm using using Breeze.WebApi2

Comment: You probably are but you might have some older dependent dlls. Nuget can be very flaky with this.  Please look at the DocCode sample.

Comment: There can't be any older dlls, because I've created new solution in VS  2013, and just copied code, and added all new packages from nuget, and here is question with same problem as mine (please see last comment) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869689/breeze-expand-results-in-object-object-has-no-method-getproperty-query-fa

Comment: If you can replicate your bug with a test added to the DocCode sample (using the DocCode dbs) I will fix it. But so far, I can't replicate your problem and we have many unit tests just like it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll try to do in it in the morning, it's getting pretty late here where I live

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it !

So the problem was here:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Supported | AllowedQueryOptions.Expand)]
        public IQueryable<Muscle> Muscles()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.Muscles;
        }
```

When I removed this line:

```
  [Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Supported | AllowedQueryOptions.Expand)]
```

It worked like a charm,

Jay thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Ah... that explains it.  The [Queryable] attribute causes WebApi/WebApi2 to use its own internal query filtering ( this is only a partial subset of the OData syntax that Breeze supports).  If you do want to use this attribute, Breeze has a [BreezeQueryable] attribute that can be used in place of [Queryable] and takes all the same arguments. Removing the attribute completely causes Breeze to use the [BreezeController] defaults ( which are Breeze compatible :))

Comment: Yes, but with "old" settings, expand works only if I have that line :)